# How do you calibrate between a mixer and recorder?

Tags: recorder-mixer

I was trying to calibrate a SQN mixer with a DEVA 5.8 using a 1 Khz tone generated from the mixer.Where will you place the master fader if it isn't depended on the tone and it does not have a marking ?
I dont know how to put this question better....

Answer (score 2):

Okay, i used SQN mixer for some time, but didn't use it with direct outputs, so I am not really familiar with how they work there. My experience is based on Sound Devices 442 mixer here.
The main use of master fader on the mixer is when you need to feed for ex. the inputs of the camera hotter, so you can raise the level of the whole mix. The tone is independent of the master fader, and it should be, as it is set in the mixer firmware at the specified level (usually 0dBu, or +4dBu). Then, what you have to do is set the gain staging right. So you have some headroom left at the mixer - let's say the tone is at 0dBu, then you set the trim on the input of the recorder so you have enough headroom left - it depends if the recorder is professional, then it can accept full analog line level which can be as high as +27dBu in Deva's 5.8 example (i didn't use DEVA 5.8 so bare with me here, the specs say the clipping level is +28dBu). So when Zaxcom specifies DEVA's Line-level Range as -26 to +8 dBu, you could set the trims on the recorder so they show -20dbfs with the tone set to 0dBu. Then you will have a lot of headroom left at both the mixer and the recorder, so you can record dynamic material. Don't worry about recording low (around -12dBfs) , because they can raise it in post. Hope it clears as much as possible:) check out this picture for the scales :

http://media.soundonsound.com/sos/oct03/images/qadbcomparison.l.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I know the procedure for calibration.But my doubt is where to keep the master faders after calibrating with 1k tone when the mic inputs are depended on them.I have used a TL audio mixer which alteast have a 0 marking for the master faders.But the SQN does'nt have one.

The model number is SQN 5s

Thnx for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, most of the time you'd keep the master at unity. If you need more level for the camera, push it more. I know that gain and fader in SQN mixers are linked, that is a difference to SD mixers. You just set them to whatever level you need at the moment. There is a very good manual here : http://www.sqn.co.uk/5Sbook.html#a9
The SQN sounds fabulous, btw. I sometimes miss the sound. Much better pres than 442. At least for my ears.

Comment: I have this manual in print and went through it.I couldn't get any help.Thanks for your feedback anyways.

Comment: Chris, what is your specific problem with SQN and the DEVA?